# Destination host unreachable while using WiFi on 2.2

Tags: wi-fi, networking

I upgraded my HTC EVO to 2.2 using a ROM I found online. (Sprint's OTA update wouldn't work)  All has been well, but I have been having troubles with my WiFi. I can connect to any AP, security or not, and I get an IP from DHCP no problem. However, I can't get online.  Using a ping tool to try to ping things on my LAN returns destination host unreachable.

The IP settings are correct. Seems my EVO's routing table is messed up. Thought's on how to narrow down the problem and/or fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out that if I disable 802.11n mode and just leave b/g enabled, then my phone works on WiFi just fine.  It seems that there was an issue using 802.11n on my phone.

I don't yet know if the issue was my AP or my phone, but I guess I will need to find a way to disable 802.11n on Froyo.